# Couchbase Testing latency of replicated data

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Consider the following scenario:
I have got a couchbase database installed in 3 different clusters. As you may know, couchbase db offers seamless selfreplication between clusters.

I would like to know, if I push some records into a cluster db, how long does it take to be replicated to the other clusters?

An original approach I am taking is:

1. Have a writer client injecting records into a cluster only.
2. have a set of clients retrieving data by connecting to the other cluster(s), they have to be constantly querying the database every second.
   Is this approach ok, or would you think of a better use case?  I know the delay between client reads would be an overhead that will affect an exact calculation.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a spring or java related question. If it is, please add some more detail. If not, please remove those tags.

Comment: Isn't there way to monitor this in Couchbase, so you don't have to write something? Under "Monitor Current Replications" perhaps? https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-xdcr/create-xdcr-replication.html#monitor-current-replications

Comment: Thanks @MatthewGroves , I just wanted to know if there is a pattern industry uses when testing latency programatically and there is no perpetual listener service. But for sure, you are right for this case thanks!